# Ansible set fact to retrieve element from json data but getting None as output

Tags: python, json, ansible

Below data is the output of a single iteration. And I wanted to get the value of the "id" field. I tried with  "`{{ item.id }}`" but it gives "None". sometimes it fails with an ansible-unsafe text error.  Please advise

- debug: "`{{ item }}`"
  with_items: "`{{ info }}`"

## The single Item of the loop looks like the below:

```
ok: [jncbfg65] => (item={u'comparison': u'above', u'select_value': u'cpuPercent', u'created_at_epoch_millis': 1589211897602, u'critical_threshold': {u'duration_minutes': 5, u'value': 95.0, u'time_function': u'all'}, u'enabled': True, u'name': u'CPU-ALERTS', u'filter': {u'and': [{u'like': {u'ec2Tag_Name': u'havc'}}]}, u'violation_close_timer': 24, u'updated_at_epoch_millis': 1659634299940, u'event_type': u'SystemSample', u'warning_threshold': {u'duration_minutes': 5, u'value': 60.0, u'time_function': u'all'}, u'policy_id': 560043, u'type': u'infra_metric', u'id': 13506855, u'description': u'Following Instance CPU utilization  has high usage, please take action accordingly'}) => {
    "123456": "123456",
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "comparison": "above",
        "created_at_epoch_millis": 1589211897602,
        "critical_threshold": {
            "duration_minutes": 5,
            "time_function": "all",
            "value": 95.0
        },
        "description": "Following Instance CPU utilization  has high usage, please take action accordingly",
        "enabled": true,
        "event_type": "SystemSample",
        "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "like": {
                        "ec2Tag_Name": "havc"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": 123456,
        "name": "CPU-ALERTS",
        "policy_id": 560043,
        "select_value": "cpuPercent",
        "type": "infra_metric",
        "updated_at_epoch_millis": 1659634299940,
        "violation_close_timer": 24,
        "warning_threshold": {
            "duration_minutes": 5,
            "time_function": "all",
            "value": 60.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone suggest ?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. According to your example I could get the id by using `item.id`

Comment: Since with the currently given information no problem is reproducible, can you provide your playbook or tasks in question?